# How to execute two types of listeners on onclick event?

Tags: android, onclick

In my application there is a panel and a Linear Layout. User may click on panel or on layout. But I need to execute panellistener event when user click on Linear layout. How can I do this in android ?

This is my code.

```
public class FindTables extends Activity implements OnPanelListener, OnClickListener {

LinearLayout overlay;
Panel panel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.findtables);

    overlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.overlay);
    overlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    panel = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.topPanel);
    panel.setOnPanelListener(this);
    panel.setInterpolator(new ExpoInterpolator(Type.OUT));

}

@Override
public void onPanelClosed(Panel panel) {
    // overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    String panelName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(panel.getId());
    Log.d("TestPanels", "Panel [" + panelName + "] closed");

}

@Override
public void onPanelOpened(Panel panel) {

    String panelName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(panel.getId());
    Log.d("TestPanels", "Panel [" + panelName + "] opened");

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.overlay:
            overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I figured out the answer by myself. There is a method called setOpen in the class Panel. It do the work I wanted. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious solution is to call appropriate OnPanelListener method (e.g. onPanelOpened or onPanelClosed) from your onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.overlay:
        overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        onPanelOpened((Panel) findViewById(R.id.topPanel));
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. There is a method called setOpen in the class Panel. It do the work I wanted. Thanks for your time.